# How to Include Zero in a COUNT() Aggregate?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have three tables, and I join them and use where Group by -  count, I could not get the countries with zero results in the output. I am still lost.

Here is the SQLfiddle

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e330ec/7

CURRENT OUTPUT

```
(UKD)   3
(EUR)   2
(USA)   2
(CHE)   1
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT

```
(UKD)   3
(EUR)   2
(IND)   0
(LAO)   0
(USA)   2
(CHE)   1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can prefer applying the following steps as an option :

- convert second `LEFT JOIN` to `RIGHT JOIN`(since desired missing abbreviations are in `COUNTRY_TABLE` which stays at right)
- make the filtering condition(followed by the `WHERE` clause) `G.GAME_TYPE = 'GOLF'` a match condition
  by taking next to the `ON` clause

such as

```
SELECT C.COUNTRY_CODE, COUNT(GAME_TYPE)
  FROM PLAYER_TABLE P
  LEFT JOIN PLAYER_GAME_TYPE G
    ON P.PLAYER_ID = G.PLAYER_ID
  RIGHT JOIN COUNTRY_TABLE C
    ON P.COUNTRY_ID = C.COUNTRY_ID
   AND G.GAME_TYPE = 'GOLF'
 GROUP BY C.COUNTRY_CODE;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/ETypjKMe)</kbd>

Comment: We should not encourage right outer joins in my opinion. They can make queries close to unreadable and thus hard to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `RIGHT JOIN` as suggested in another answer or you can reorder your joins and use a `LEFT JOIN`:

```sql
SELECT
  C.COUNTRY_CODE,
  COUNT(GAME_TYPE)
FROM
  COUNTRY_TABLE C
  LEFT JOIN PLAYER_TABLE P ON P.COUNTRY_ID = C.COUNTRY_ID
  LEFT JOIN PLAYER_GAME_TYPE G ON P.PLAYER_ID = G.PLAYER_ID
WHERE
  G.GAME_TYPE = 'GOLF'
  OR G.GAME_TYPE IS NULL
GROUP BY
  C.COUNTRY_CODE;
```

Note the inclusion of `OR G.GAME_TYPE IS NULL` in the `WHERE` clause -- if you only have `G.GAME_TYPE = 'GOLF'`, then desired results will be filtered out *after the joins*.

Answer (score 1):

The simple change of tables join order can solve the problem

```
SELECT C.COUNTRY_CODE, COUNT(GAME_TYPE)
FROM COUNTRY_TABLE C -- get all countries
LEFT JOIN PLAYER_TABLE P ON P.COUNTRY_ID = C.COUNTRY_ID -- join all players
LEFT JOIN PLAYER_GAME_TYPE G ON P.PLAYER_ID = G.PLAYER_ID AND G.GAME_TYPE = 'GOLF' -- join only GOLF games
GROUP BY C.COUNTRY_CODE;
```

[sqlize online](https://sqlize.online/sql/oracle21/70b8116daa4d6eefde679ed1f38f4b40/)

Answer (score 0):

This is your query:

```
SELECT C.COUNTRY_CODE, COUNT(GAME_TYPE)
FROM PLAYER_TABLE P 
LEFT JOIN PLAYER_GAME_TYPE G ON P.PLAYER_ID = G.PLAYER_ID
LEFT JOIN COUNTRY_TABLE C ON P.COUNTRY_ID = C.COUNTRY_ID
WHERE G.GAME_TYPE = 'GOLF'
GROUP BY C.COUNTRY_CODE;
```

This query seems to try to select all players even when they are no golfers. This doesn't work, however, as `WHERE G.GAME_TYPE = 'GOLF'` removes all outer joined rows, so you end up with an inner join (all players who play golf.) At last you outer join the countries table, which would give you players that don't belong to a country. Is this indented? I don't think so.

What you want is countries, so select from countries. Then properly outer join players and types in order to count them.

```
SELECT c.country_code, COUNT(g.game_type) as golfers_in_country
FROM country_table c
LEFT JOIN player_table p ON p.country_id = c.country_id
LEFT JOIN player_game_type g ON g.player_id = p.player_id AND g.game_type = 'GOLF'
GROUP BY c.country_code
ORDER BY c.country_code;
```

You can use a CTE to get this more readable. It is longer, but makes the intention crystal-clear. Structuring one's queries like this helps avoiding mistakes.

```
WITH golfers AS
(
  SELECT *
  FROM player_table
  WHERE player_id IN
  (
    SELECT player_id
    FROM player_game_type
    WHERE game_type = 'GOLF'
  )
)
SELECT c.country_code, COUNT(g.player_id) as golfers_in_country
FROM country_table c
LEFT JOIN golfers g ON g.country_id = c.country_id
GROUP BY c.country_code
ORDER BY c.country_code;
```